# How significant is the order with jQuery's trigger-method?

Tags: event-handling, jquery, jquery-on

I want to provide a way to use an `on`-event handler from the outside of a plugin. Problem is, that the trigger will not fired if I provide them in wrong order.

For example, this works:

```
$(window).on('foo:bar', function(){
    alert(true);
});
$(window).trigger('foo:bar');
```

...this, however does not:

```
$(window).trigger('foo:bar');
$(window).on('foo:bar', function(){
    alert(true);
});
```

Any ideas how the second approach can work?

**Update**

Here it works: http://www.benplum.com/projects/rubberband/

Comment: ??confused?? The first one *doesn't work*.  The second one does.

Comment: Okay, so you've swapped the examples now :)

Comment: @Archer Yeah, I'm a bit tired :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. You want to eat cake before baking it.

UPD: You're misinterpreting the code at http://www.benplum.com/projects/rubberband/

Here is a jsfiddle with proof that it doesn't work like you're thinking: [jsfiddle.net/zerkms/z5Mya/](http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/z5Mya/)

Note about code: I've forked the library and added trivial `console.log` here: https://github.com/zerkms/Rubberband/blob/master/jquery.bp.rubberband.js#L77

Comment: Harr, nice answer! However, I've already seen that it works: https://github.com/benplum/Rubberband/blob/master/jquery.bp.rubberband.js#L79

Comment: @yckart: I don't see where they add event handler

Comment: @yckart: also check https://github.com/benplum/Rubberband/blob/master/jquery.bp.rubberband.js#L42 - that method is called **after** the handlers are attached

Comment: No, they trigger the `rubberband` event with namespace `enter` and later it can used by the user to determine if an action was done: http://www.benplum.com/projects/rubberband/ (last section *examples*) The `rubberband`-event is never called in the plugin itself...

Comment: @yckart: nope, the `$(window).on` is called **before** the event is triggered - I've given you a link to `setTimeout` that delays triggering

Comment: Yes, that the `setTimeout` triggers not the `rubberband` it triggers resize... or doesn't matter which event has been triggered? no! ;)

Comment: @yckart I think you're misreading that code.  The triggers are only ever called in event handlers, one of which is the `_init` event, which is only called after all functions have been declared.  None of the event handlers can be called before the function is declared - it's not possible

Comment: Yes, Sorry! My fault, damn... Thanks!

Comment: I cannot give you more than 1 *+1* but I would ;-)